# Parsing CGI Query String Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

One method of Parsing the Query string data is:

```
GLOBAL={}
"?a=1&b=3&D123=Hello world".replace(
  new RegExp(/([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g),
  function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
    GLOBAL[$1]=$3
  }
)
```

I'm new to RegEx and was wondering if anyone could explain the how the RegEx expression works with the variables $0,$1,$2,$3 to make it so that GLOBAL[a] = 1 in this example.

If $1 = first grouping, $2 = second grouping, etc. What is the need for $0?

Comment: A lot of online tools already offer to do that: [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iD1fH5), http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl ... Have you tried some of them?

Comment: I should have reworded my question. I don't really understand how it works with the variables to store the correct name:value pairs.

Comment: There's too many parentheses in that regex... but anyway, it's just a basic callback. Parameters are filled according to the rules of the function, in this case `replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally considered better practice to give your callback parameters meaningful names, specifically to help with understanding. Personally, I would write your code as:

```
... .replace(
    /([^?=&]+)(?:=([^&]*))?/g, // note slightly different regex ;)
    function( _, key, value) {
        GLOBALS[key] = value;
    }
);
```

See how much easier it is to understand what's going on just by reading? `_` is a convention to mean "we're not interested in this parameter" (which makes the "underscore" library laughable to me... XD)

In any case, as with all callbacks the parameters depend entirely on what the function decides to pass. In the case of `.replace()`, the first parameter is the whole match, then from then on the captured subpatterns are given one after the other - this is why I said there were "too many parentheses" in my comment, you can see in my version I used `(?:` to designate a *non-capturing* subpattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will definitely use meaningful names in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been answered, your `$0` variable will contain the part of the input string that was matched by the **whole** expression, as opposed to the matches in parenthesis.

As for what you're trying to do, you could populate your GLOBALS object using a replace callback, but in order to populate more than just the first parameter, try as follows:

```
var GLOBALS = {},
    query = "?a=1&b=3&D123=Hello world",
    expr = /^(?:\?|&)([^=&]*)(?:=([^&]*))?/g;

while( query = query.replace( expr, function( match, prop, value ){
    GLOBALS[ decodeURIComponent(prop||'') ] = decodeURIComponent(value||'');
    return '';
} ) );
```

This allows an arbitrary number of arguments in your string, but carries the risk that if the query is badly formed you could get an **infinite loop** as it won't stop until the input string is exhausted.

Less risky would be this:

```
while( match = /^(?:\?|&)([^=&]*)(?:=([^&]*))?/g.exec(query) ){
    query = query.substr( match[0].length );
    GLOBALS[ decodeURIComponent(match[1]||'') ] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]||'');
}
```

However, matching each parameter with RegExp is probably not the best approach. Personally, I'd do this:

```
var pairs = query.split(/[\?&]/), pair, p;
for( p in pairs ){
     if( pairs[p] ){
        pair = pairs[p].split('=',2);
        GLOBALS[ decodeURIComponent(pair[0]||'') ] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]||'');
    }
}
```